# The last digit of $n!$ for $n \ge 5$ is always $0$. What are the options for the last non-zero digit of $n!, n\ge 5$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I've found formulas online that use the greatest integer function, but they seem to answer my question for specific values of $n$. Is there an easier approach to find all values the last non-zero digit of a random $n$ can take? Is there another way to find these values (so not necessarily using the formulas with $\left\lfloor\cdots\right\rfloor$)?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/last-non-zero-digit-factorial/

Comment: Note that you get $k$ additional zeros every $a5^k$ terms where $a \in \mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: For $n>1$ the last non-zero digit of $n!$ has to be even since the exponent of $2$ in the prime expansion of $n!$ is greater than the exponent of $5$ (i.e. in $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ there are more even numbers than multiples of $5$).

Comment: This is [A008904](https://oeis.org/A008904).